# Uploading video from camera roll with Expo (React Native)

Tags: react-native, expo

I am able to get the ImagePicker working, but is there any way to uplaod video currently using Expo?

If not do I need to eject from expo and use the React Native camera roll?

I am curious what steps to take to get video uploading working with Expo (React Native)

Answer (score 0):

The expo team are working hard on bringing in new features. As of now video recording/streaming is still under development. 
You can stay updated at https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/camera-component